# Javascript shift() for Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I want to take my list and add the first two (0 & 1) items together.

I tried this:

```
        total=foo.shift();
        foo[0]=total
```

And got this:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'

I then tried to simply call "foo" and output it; same error.
This leads me to think that it is not in a form I can work with without some workaround.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You want `shift` or `split`? Either way, explain with sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Please show us at least the line that throws the error - if not just all your code, so that we can properly reproduce your problem.

Comment: A variable that you expect to be a string is an array, that's what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a working code that can help you:

```
        //we initialize an array with two objects
        var arr=[{'id':1,'nom':'ali'},{'id':2,'nom':'ahmed'}];
         console.log(arr);
        //array with two objects displayed in the console: [Object, Object]

        //we call shift method       
        arr.shift();

        console.log(arr);
       //array with one object displayed in the console: [Object]
```